# Can you delete a range of lines in sublime text2?

Tags: sublimetext2

Say I want to delete lines 5000 - 9000 in a large data file. Can I delete a range of lines easily?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`LineJumper`](https://github.com/hypebeast/LineJumper) plugin. It's marked in Package Control as ST3-only, but it should work fine with ST2, only you'll have to `git clone` the repository into your `Packages` directory. Once you've done that, open `Packages/LineJumper/LineJumper.sublime-settings` and edit the `"number_of_lines"` argument to the number of lines you want to select (in this case, 4000). Save the file, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and type in `5000` to jump to line 5000. Next, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> to jump down 4000 lines, selecting them all. Finally, hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> and you're all set. The plugin could probably be modified to open a popup to enter the lines to be selected, if you don't want to edit the `.sublime-settings` file every time you want to select a large block of text, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

The manual answer with no plugins.

- Cut from the first location (e.g line 5000) to the end of the file
- Paste this into another/new window
- Find the second location (e.g. line 4000 (=9000-5000))
- Cut from here to the start of the file
- Cut everything that is left and paste it back in the first file at the end.

This is easier than scrolling from start to finish of large sections you want to remove, and the effort does not depend on the size you want to remove (but it's still not fully satisfying...).